# Chapters are not numbered

Tags: chapters

I feel like over the last couple years I've become decent writing in LaTeX.  But, for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out how to number chapters inline.

For instance, this snippet:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents{}
    \chapter{Editing compile}
    \section{First Compile}
    how to compile basic hello world into a pdf.
    Write your favorite text editor create file and copy/paste the following (with hello.tex):
    
    \subsection{Output formats}
    
    different output formats (dvi, pdf)
    
    The output of this command \$latex hello.tex will be a dvi 
    file (hello.dvi). This file (.dvi) can be converted by \$dvipdf 
    hello.dvi The get an pdf file from tex file, run this 
    command \$texi2pdf hello.tex
    
    \chapter{Document Structure}
    
    \section{Reserved Characters}
    
    The following symbols characters are reserved by LATEX because 
    they introduce a command and have a special meaning.
    
\end{document}
```

There is a whole title "Chapter 1".  But the chapter title is "Editing Compile." Is it possible to do something like "1. Editing compile"

Comment: please don't make external links especially to a large git repository that does not apparently have the problem you are asking about (the example pdf has numbered chapters) please make a small complete example of your problem and add it to the question.  look out for setting of `secnumdepth` that is usual reason numbering is suppresssed

Comment: The problem with the template exists.  Specifically, https://github.com/josephcslater/WSUThesisTemplate/blob/master/WSUThesisTemplate.pdf on Pages 1 and 10. The chapters are headed without numbers. I don't know how to include a small complete example because the template itself is huge.   If I recreate the problem I can number then.  I'll check for secnumdepth though. thanks!

Comment: so it does sorry I only got as far as the numbered table of contents. That proves the point though you should make a self contained example. You can't expect other people to wade through that (and your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if that repository changes)

Comment: This, I guess `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\DOCH}{}%This gets rid of the text
                                %"Chapter..." in the chapter title
\makeatother`

Comment: the `\renewcommand{\DOCH}{}%This gets rid of the text "Chapter..." in the chapter title` in the sty removes the chapter prefix. But why do you use a three years old template, for which you probably won't get much support?

Comment: Thanks! I actually edited the text after being able to reproduce it. @UlrikeFischer Well, thesis template don't change much for universities.  My advisor complained because the chapters were not numbered.  So, I decided to see if it was simple, and it didn't seem like it.  I was able to reproduce the functionality I want (edited post) and hopefully can adapt that into the template.